# Is it possible to individually control each LED the way this schematic is designed?

Tags: led, schematics, serial

I'm currently researching a design which includes the below schematic :

[image: led array schematic]

This is supposed to be an array of LEDs which are attached to the front panel of the device for indicator lights.

However, I am confused as these indicator lights are clearly supposed to be individually activated, but this schematic seems to have each LED in some sort of flip-flop configuration, which would seem like they are dependent upon each other's states.

The global label `LED_SERIAL_DRV_5V` on the left is serial, so I am assuming that the input for lighting LED 3 would be 00100000.

Is there an obvious flaw in how this schematic is designed or is it actually possible to individually control each of the LEDs?

Comment: Read the [datasheet](https://www.americanbrightled.com/pdffiles/led-components/plcc/BB-HRGB32M-TRB.pdf) for the LEDs. These are more than just LEDs, they contain some simple processing to make them individually addressible in a chain like this. The datasheet doesn't seem to really explain how to do that very well, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leds use a typical NZR single wire protocol, reading the data like a shift register. They accept 24 bits to determine their state, and then pass along the rest of the data out of DOUT to the next led which does the same, until they receive a reset signal. This is how most smart individually addressable leds work, as a serial  chain. Individually addressable leds with a bus topology do exist but not as often, with significantly more complicated protocols (bi-directional or preassigned serial numbers or more pins, i2c etc.)

The addressable part is a bit of misnomer as you don't directly address a specific led here, you just spit data out in a predetermined manner. Some methods require a memory/frame buffer to track the state of the leds as you need to send the data out again in n seconds, while others will retain their state and have passthrough options etc etc.

Those leds seems to be compatible with the standard ws2812b type protocol. This specific schematic looks bog standard and works as designed.

The IC to the left is being used as either a buffer or inverter.